# Alamofire No exact matches in call to class method 'jsonObject'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire like so:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .accept("application/json")
        ]

let credential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "p@ssword", persistence: .none)
        
        AF.request(webservice, headers: headers).authenticate(with: credential).responseDecodable(of: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>.self) { response in
            print(response)
        }
```

But I am getting this error:

> Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Decodable'

I am just switching to Alamofire and my call is working, but formatting the data is not, how I use to get the data was the following:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            
            if(error != nil){
                
                completion(false)
                
            }else{
                
                do{
                    
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>
                    
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        
                        completion(json)
                        
                    })
                    
                }catch let error as NSError{
                    
                    print(error)
                    completion(false)
                    
                }
            }
            
        }).resume()
```

UPDATE

I changed my call to this:

```
AF.request(webservice, headers: headers).authenticate(with: credential).response { response in
            print(response)
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>
            }catch let error as NSError{
            }
        }
```

But I get this error now: No exact matches in call to class method 'jsonObject'

Comment: `response!` is not a `Data` object, that's why... It's `response.data`, or `response.response.data`, I don't remember exactly...

Comment: Unrelated, but `options:.allowFragments` is useless, since according to your code you expect a `Dictionary`, and not just a String, Int... Any reason why not use `Codable`? And `catch let error as NSError` can be just `catch`.

Comment: @Larme response.data worked! Thanks!

Comment: Stop decoding JSON manually and use `responseDecodable` with a proper type.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error is

```
No exact matches in call to class method 'jsonObject'
```

So it means, that `JSONSerialization`, has a static method that look alike, but it's not the same.

So when you encounter this issue, it's usually a typo or bad type.
In your case, it's bad types.

Let's start by check the type of `response`.
You might need to comment the lines that causes the error first.
Mouse over the `response`, keep Option key tapped (the cursors transforms into a question mark), and then click on `response`.
You'll get its type: `AFDataResponse<Data?>`.

Now, let's see [`JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) doc, and it has these two methods (I strongly guess you want the first one):

```
class func jsonObject(with: Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions) -> Any

class func jsonObject(with: InputStream, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions) -> Any
```

See the issue?

```
Data != AFDataResponse<Data?>
```

To access the `Data` object from `response`, it's with `response.data`:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>
```

Unrelated, but since it's a SO question, we tend to often go strictly to the issue, but I noticed a few things though, and I wouldn't want someone to replicate them when learning.

Now, you are using force unwrap (use of `!`), if there is an issue: `response.data` being nil, `json` not being a `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>`, it will crash, just for your information.

`catch let error as NSError` can be replaced with just `catch`

`options:.allowFragments` is not needed. To be needed, the JSON needs to be just a `Bool`, a `String`, or a `Number`. In other words, at top level it's not an `Array` nor a `Dictionary`.

You might also want to check the success or not of the response, else the whole response might be different, and then, it might not be a `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>` and will crash. We might imagine responding a 500 error with a HTML error code, and you `as!` will make it crash.

So, I'd write it that way:

```
AF.request(webservice, headers: headers).authenticate(with: credential).response { response in
    print(response)
    
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        do {
            guard let data = data else { print("Success, but empty response"); return }
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
            guard let jsonDict = json as? [String: [String: Any]] else {
                print("JSON is not a [String: [String: Any]]: \(json)")
                return
            }
            //Use jsonDict
        } catch {
            print("Error while decoding: \(error)")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```